# Как img понял куда надо разместить фотографии?

Tags: css, img, display

Мне помогли с кодом, но я не смог понять почему img пошли направо а не налево в коде я не вижу никакого их направления.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CSS
body {
background-color: #fff;
 color: #333;
 margin: 0;
 font: 1.2em / 1.2 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
}

.logo {
 font-size: 200%;
 padding: 30px 20px;
 margin-left: 150px;
 max-width: 980px;
}

.grid {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 20px;
 max-width: 980px;
 display: flex;
}

li {
 display: inline;
}

nav {
 background-color: #000;
 padding: .5em;
 text-align: center;
 position: sticky;
}

nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav a {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: .5em 1em;
 
}

.photos {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 gap: 5px;
}

.photos li {
 max-width: calc(50% - 8px);
 width: calc(50% - 8px);
}

.feature {
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

article {
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Layout Task</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="logo"> My exciting website! </h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Our history</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main class="grid">
    <article>
      <h1>
        An Exciting Blog Post
      </h1>
      <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder" class="feature">
      <p>Veggies es bonus vobis, proinde vos postulo essum magis kohlrabi welsh onion daikon amaranth tatsoi tomatillo melon azuki bean garlic.</p>

      <p>Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.</p>

      <p>Turnip greens yarrow ricebean rutabaga endive cauliflower sea lettuce kohlrabi amaranth water spinach avocado daikon napa cabbage asparagus winter purslane kale. Celery potato scallion desert raisin horseradish spinach carrot soko. Lotus root water
        spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea. Brussels sprout coriander water chestnut gourd swiss chard wakame kohlrabi beetroot carrot watercress. Corn amaranth salsify bunya nuts
        nori azuki bean chickweed potato bell pepper artichoke.</p>

      <p>Nori grape silver beet broccoli kombu beet greens fava bean potato quandong celery. Bunya nuts black-eyed pea prairie turnip leek lentil turnip greens parsnip. Sea lettuce lettuce water chestnut eggplant winter purslane fennel azuki bean earthnut
        pea sierra leone bologi leek soko chicory celtuce parsley jícama salsify.</p>

      <p>Celery quandong swiss chard chicory earthnut pea potato. Salsify taro catsear garlic gram celery bitterleaf wattle seed collard greens nori. Grape wattle seed kombu beetroot horseradish carrot squash brussels sprout chard.</p>

    </article>

    <aside>
      <h2>
        Photography
      </h2>
      <ul class="photos">
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="https://placehold.jp/3d4070/ffffff/150x150.png" alt="placeholder">
        </li>
      </ul>

    </aside>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

PS: Я про те картинки которые под Photography, вопрос в том как они там окозались. Спасибо :3

Comment: Потому что таковы параметры flex-разметки по умолчанию (flex-direction: row и т.п.)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у тебя есть блок `main` с параметром `display: flex` внутри которого два блока `article` и  `aside`, которые расположены согласно flex-разметке. И те фотографии, которые справа, они находятся в блоке `aside`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не очень понял, но теперь есть что в гугл забить и понять flex разметку Спасибо большое :3